# Getting the name of a row's table in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

(I'm not entirely sure how to word this question, which made Googling it a fruitless challenge, so I hope that this question isn't too common or poorly-worded.)

I'm working on **a web application in PHP and MySQL that will allow a user to search through a database made up of 12 tables** (so every entry on the results page could be from any one of 12 tables). Pretty simple stuff, and the search functionality is already there and working great. Now I want for the user to be able to click an entry in the search results and be taken to a page that is populated with the details for that particular result (very similar to running a search on Stack Overflow, then clicking one of the results to be taken to the full question / answer page for that particular result).

I figure the easiest way to do this would be URL parameters: one for the ID of the result (the row number, basically), and one for the table name, so that on the results page I can just tell it which table and row to reference and then fill in the information from there. I can get the ID just fine (as it's one of the columns in the tables), but **I can't figure out how to tell PHP which table the given row is from so that I may pass its name into the URL**. (Example: User clicks on a result that is row 4 from a table called "employees". URL parameters would become `?table=employees&id=4`. The "employees" part is where I'm having issues.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :) Abridged relevant code below:

```
[...]

// The 12 tables are split across two languages, so the loop is made of two parts -- an English loop and a Japanese loop. lineToString() is a custom function that replaces the numeric result from the line select dropdown with the proper text name for the line.
if ($line < 1 || $line > 6) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $lineName = lineToString($i);
        $completedQuery = $completedQuery."SELECT * FROM en_".$lineName." WHERE MATCH (report,counter) AGAINST ('%".$query."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
        $completedQuery = $completedQuery." UNION ALL ";
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $lineName = lineToString($i);
        $completedQuery = $completedQuery."SELECT * FROM jp_".$lineName." WHERE MATCH (report,counter) AGAINST ('%".$query."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
        if ($i < 6) {
            $completedQuery = $completedQuery." UNION ALL ";
        }
    }
}

$result = mysql_query($completedQuery) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($results['report'] == NULL) {
            echo "<td height=\"25px\"></td>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<td><a href=\"report.php?line=".TABLE-NAME-HERE."&report=".$results['id']."\">".Truncate($results['report'], 100)."</a></td>\n";
        }

[...]
```

Comment: how are mysql_* functions still in use, there should be an auto comment generated on any questions containing one. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php http://uk1.php.net/mysqli - I apologise that this doesn't attempt to answer your question :)

Comment: Haha, sorry about that, man. I blame the fact that so many of the more useful PHP resources are outdated. :P I'll be reading into Mysqli and PDO now, thanks!

Comment: So what does your query for searching in multiple tables look like?

Comment: Suppose I should have included that from the start. :) It's up there now. Probably a little primitive, but it works, haha.

Comment: First, it sounds like you have a DB schema design problem.  Why would you search across 12 different tables and then not even know what table you are querying from?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the $completedQuery variable. Basically $completedQuery must be like

```
$completedQuery = "select * from ".$table_name." where search_term like '%userdata%'";
```

This means you already know the table name, because you're querying it. You can use $table_name variable in report url.

Comment: True, and this works for when the user is searching just one table. But the user can be looking across as many as 12 tables, with $table_name only ever pointing to the last table referenced in the loop that creates the MySQL query. Unless I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `mysql_tablename()`.

You can look it up at php.net

Still I would prefer the use of PDO..